# Binding asp.net MVC 5 to derived class without custom binder polymorphism

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, model-binding

I would like to know if there is a way to bind (in POST/PUT) derived class from an abstract base class or interface, in details in my model I have a `List<AbstractClass>` in this list I have for example objects from `DerivedClass1 : AbstractClass` and `DerivedClass2 : AbstractClass` now when i post the Json of my model via ajax to my controller this list are filled by `AbstractClass` object so I lost all the derived class properties.

Then the question at hand, are there some ways to bind the derived class properties without custom binder?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Short answer is no.

Comment: lol @StephenMuecke thanks!